# Jupiter notebook stuck

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open a Jupyter notebook I have done, but since when I uploaded a huge dataframe it is stuck like this:

[image]

I don't know what to do actually. I have tried to ctrl+C (force quit) jupyter and restart it again several times. I have an important code there. Is there a way to recover it or open the page? I know it's not very much info. This notebook is stored in an anaconda environment and for the moment I did nothing but trying to open it....it looks like jupyter is very slow down.

EDIT: it looks like it is very memory expensive...
[image]

Thank you,

Federico

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter notebooks are actually JSON files, so you can open them with plain text editors. Presumably, your browser is having a hard time rendering the notebook - opening it in a text editor won't render anything at all, so you should be able to read the code.

This will allow you to back up the code of the notebook.

Comment: thank you for the reply. So Actually the problem is that the notebook is 167MB due to a display I made by mistake. So I cannot even open the notebook. Is there a shell command to do that? I tried this: jupyter nbconvert Notebooks/Riccaboni/second/Test_del_codice_2021-Copy1.ipynb --to notebook --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --output Notebooks/Riccaboni/second/Test_del_codice_2021-Copy1.ipynb
 but does not work. It says Notebooks/Riccaboni/second/Test_del_codice_2021-Copy1.ipynb not found

Comment: @NutarelliFederico, did you mean `jupyter nbconvert Notebooks/Riccaboni/second/Test_del_codice_2021.ipynb --to notebook --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --output Notebooks/Riccaboni/second/Test_del_codice_2021-Copy1.ipynb`? The command in your code attempts to convert the file called, `Test_del_codice_2021-Copy1.ipynb`, but it's not there